# Как завставить snmpget отправлять запросы с 162 порта

Tags: linux, snmp

Есть железка, с включеным snmp. Родная программа ( под винду ) делает запросы по snmp к железке и в качестве src port использует 162. Пробую получить значения oid из linux, с помощью snmpget или snmpwalk, но в ответ получаю timeout. Исследование wireshark показывают, что родная программа использует src порт 162, а snmpget или snmpwalk произвольный src порт.

Как заставить snmpget отправлять запросы с 162 порта?

[image: wireshark]

Comment: https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/utilities/s/snmpget.htm `-p`?

Comment: @donRumata Ссылка ведет на несуществующую страницу.

Comment: @donRumata я так понял вы про эту ссылку http://www.qnx.co.jp/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/utilities/s/snmpget.html
Но даже здесь опция -p устанавливает порт назначения, а мне надо поменять порт источника

Comment: Странно, у меня ссылка открывалась. А щас - да, болты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вопрос про src порт оказался не корректным, `ping` и `snmp` запросы не работали в linux из за флага `DF` (dont fragment), в винде все пакеты без `DF` флага...
Cнять DF можно установив `1` для `net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc`

Comment: Китайцы такие китайцы...